# Logging into an MVC3 app doesn't remember who I am

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I have an MVC3 application using NHibernate.  I've created my own membership and role providers and they're working ok.  I have a problem with logging in though (probably due to inexperience with ASP.NET security).  I wonder if someone could help me.

Here's my controller

```
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
       ...
```

I have a login url setup in Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/User/Login" timeout="2880" cookieless="AutoDetect" />
</authentication>
```

So, when I try and click the edit link I get forwarded to the login page.  All well and good so far.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_membershipProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(model.UserName, model.Password);        
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserName, false);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I then get forwarded to the page I came from but when I click the Edit link again I get sent back to the login page.  How do I get ASP.NET to store the user in session or something so that it remembers me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass "true" to that :

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserName, true);
```

From here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce(v=VS.100).aspx

> **userName**  The authenticated user name.
>
> **createPersistentCookie**  true to create a
>   durable cookie (one that is saved
>   across browser sessions); otherwise,
>   false.